# Power Analysis for Text Mining

Tags: sample-size, text-mining, statistical-power, sentiment-analysis

I have a population of 6 million text files with which I want to perform sentiment analysis (and text analysis more generally). I will need to manually hand code a subset of these texts into positive and negative. Is there an equivalent of a "power calculation" or rules of thumb to help me determine how large my sample needs to be such that I am 80% accurate when I apply the algorithm to the full population (i.e. those that are not hand-coded)?

I understand I can calculate accuracy/sensitivity/specificity/etc for the manually hand coded sample. But if I get 80% accuracy on 600 texts, I don't think I can extrapolate this 80% to the full 6 million.

I'm aware of this thread: [Text mining "power calculations"?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22690/text-mining-power-calculations)